# My program crashes while comparing elements in array

Tags: c, arrays, function, crash

Hi I need help with my program. Part of code does not seem to work as expected:

```
void up(int pole[4][4])
{

int i,j;

for (i = 3; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (j = 3; j >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (pole[i][j] == pole[i-1][j])
        {
            pole[i-1][j] += pole[i][j];
            pole[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

system("cls");

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", pole[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

when I call the function up in switch like this:

```
    switch(keynumber)
    {
    case 119: //w
        up(base);
        break;
```

I just end up with my program crashing.
The reason why I am doing this is that I want to make 2048 game in console so first I created an array of which 2 random elements of the array will be the number 2 and then I compare these elements depending on which key you will push.

Comment: `for (j = 3; j >= 0; i--)` : `i--` --> `j--`

Comment: yeh what @BLUEPIXY said, you are subtrating from I rather than J, resulting in an infinite loop

Comment: VTC as typo....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 3; i >= 1; i--)
{
       for (j = 3; j >= 0; i--)  // Why here is i-- ?? instead if j-- 
           {
              if (pole[i][j] == pole[i-1][j])
                {
                 pole[i-1][j] += pole[i][j];
                 pole[i][j] = 0;
                 }
            }
}
```

When the second loop is breaking?

Answer (score 0):

Refer line number 8,
Instead of

```
    for (j = 3; j >= 0; i--)
```

it should be

```
    for (j = 3; j >= 0; j--)
```

As value of j isn't decrementing, it is an infinite loop.